# Writing / reading file in the internal storage of Android (the file disappears)

Tags: java, android

I have a class which write a png in the internal storage. When I write and read it just after that, it works.

```
FileOutputStream fileOutStream = openFileOutput(filepath,
                    Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, fileOutStream);
fileOutStream.close();
```

(the type of Bitmap is a Bitmap)

```
FileInputStream fileInStream = openFileInput(filepath);
byte[] fileContent = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toByteArray(fileInStream);
```

When I use the same read function, with the same filepath parameter (I verify id), but in another class, it doesn't work.

Is there a limitation when using with another class of the same project ?

Regards

Comment: Its not because you didn't flush the fileOutStream with      fileOutStream.flush(); before closing it?

Comment: i tryied to flush it before but i removed it between my different try. it's very strange to read it the first time but not the second ...

Comment: Did you close fileInStream after first reading ?

Comment: Where exactly do you store your file? - In some kind of *temp* directory ('/tmp',...)?

Comment: i store signature of the users which are sync to a web service. I musn't loose them. Mohammed it was simply just that, can you post an answer and I'll mark you. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure there is only one underlying stream on this file? because if you have multiple stream and call close() method, this will enforce to close all other streams.. so correct implementation is to close the last stream or apply flush to each one .. and close the last .. btw: for a single process of stream writing there is no need to explicitly call flush() method, because close() methods will call it implicitly.